# If $K \subset L \subset \overline{L}=\overline{K}$, then is it true that $\sigma\in Aut(\overline{L}\mid K)$ satisfies $\sigma|_L\in Aut(L\mid K)$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, normal-extension

We consider a tower of fields $K \subset L \subset \overline{L}=\overline{K}$. Is it true that, given a $\sigma\in \text{Aut}(\overline{L}\mid K)$, we can restrict it to an automorphism of $L$, that  is,  $\sigma|_L\in \text{Aut}(L\mid K)$ ? Here $\text{Aut}(L\mid K)$ means the group of automorphisms of $L$ that fix $K$.

This affirmative was implicit in a proof I saw in a paper. I know that both $\overline{L}\mid K$ and $\overline{L}\mid L$ are normal extensions, but I don't know if it helps to see the result (if it is true).

Comment: What if $K=\Bbb{Q}$, $L=\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2)$ and $\overline{L}$ is the normal closure. It may well happen $\sigma(\root3\of2)$ is non-real, when $\sigma$ is not an automorphism of $L$. In other words, you need $L/K$ to be normal, or some other special circumstance. Like $Aut(\overline{L}/K)$ abelian.

Comment: Thank you @JyrkiLahtonen! I'll think more about it.